# How to center element in layout in vuetify?

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

In vuetify, I want to horizontally/vertically center a spinning wheel. I have this so far
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rXGyVE?&editable=true&editors=101 but it does not center vertically. How can I fix that?

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-card height="200">
        <v-layout column align-center justify-center>
            <v-flex>
                <v-progress-circular indeterminate :size="50" color="primary" class=""></v-progress-circular>
            <v-flex>
        </v-layout>
     </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

})
```

Answer (score 5):

This appear work:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify()
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-card height="200">
        <v-layout align-center justify-center column fill-height>
            <v-flex row align-center>
                <v-progress-circular indeterminate :size="50" color="primary" class=""></v-progress-circular>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
     </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain the changes so that beginners can understand.

Comment: What question do you have? Maybe we can help :)